# Guess autogenerated ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My web form contains list of dynamic fields that are generated like this:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++) { %>
...
    <%= Html.Hidden("Options[" + i + "].Id", Model.Options[i].Id)%>
    <%= Html.CheckBox("Options[" + i + "].Selected", Model.Options[i].Selected)%>
...
```

This maps perfectly on array of controller method parameters as described in [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) article.

I want to add label for checkboxes to title them, but I have to guess their ids in hmtl layout.

`Options[" + i + "].Selected`  turns into `Options_0__Selected`.

So I add code like this:

```
<label for="Option_<%=i%>__Selected"><%: Model.Option[i].Title%></label>
```

How can I avoid hardcoding Id generation in-built asp.net mvc rules?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using [editor templates](http://lsd.luminis.nl/asp-net-mvc-editor-templates/) - no more magic strings:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Options) %>
```

And then you place a `Option.ascx` in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<YourNamespace.Option>" %>

<%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) %>
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Selected) %>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected) %>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a closer look. Thank you.